# How to display static (shared) object's properties in a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, static, propertygrid

I would like to display static (shared) objects at runtime in a PropertyGrid but if I try to set the selected object property of the grid like this:

```
_propertyGrid.SelectedObject = System.Windows.Forms.Application
```

I get a compilation error:

> 'Application' is a type and cannot be
>   used as an expression.

Is there a way to display a static (shared) object or the object's properties in the PropertyGrid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That assignment statement really doesn't make sense from an OO-perspective because a static object really isn't an object -- it's just a collection of methods and properties without any kind of coherence except for the class name. I see what you're trying to do, though.

You need to give it an object instance.

I would suggest creating a wrapper class (possibly a singleton) that exposes the properties you need from the `Application` object and using that as a data source instead.

Comment: This is an interesting OOP question that i never actually had to think about before. Besides trying to display a static object in the grid view this question also applies more broadly to something like passing static objects as function arguments. Looks like you can't. Not in .NET anyway.